# What's cheapest way to make a sound?

Tags: sound

We have a portable small toy which we want to make a sound on it when is connected to socket. I don't know if we must use a little speaker with a magnet or maybe we can make a noise with a mechanical object (like a beat on a very small bell). It must be as cheap and small as possible. Thank you and sorry for this noob question.

Comment: my guess is a piezo buzzer http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&KeyWords=PS1240+buzzer

Answer (score 8):

A piezo speaker (Piezoelectric Transducer) is most likely what your looking for. They are quite cheap, usually around $1, and small! There are also many other alternatives, take a look at [Loudspeaker Drivers Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudspeaker#Other_driver_designs).

[image]

[image]

You could even try to make your own, not that I would recommend it. [How to make your own piezoelectric speaker](http://hackaday.com/2012/09/15/how-to-make-your-own-piezoelectric-speaker/).

Comment: The sound they make depends on the signal you drive them with.  They don't make a "high pitched" sound on their own just because power is applied.  Just to make a beep, you generally apply a square wave.  These things have limited frequency range, usually centered around 1.5-2 kHz.  They aren't much good for reproducing general sounds like voice or music, but are fine for artificial sounds like clicks and beeps where you can pick the frequency.

Comment: @OlinLathrop thanks, I removed that. It was from the link for the Piezo Buzzer.